# network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="maticmum", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethers.js

This is the context

```
  //List Products
  const listProducts = async (
    seller,
    price,
    rating,
    name,
    description,
    category,
    imgUrl
  ) => {
   try {
    const contract = await connectingWithSmartContract();
    const prices = ethers.utils.parseEther(price, 18).toString()
    const getListedProducts = await contract.listNewProduct(
    seller,
    prices,
    rating,
    name,
    description,
    category,
    imgUrl
    )
    alert("products listed sucessfully");
    return getListedProducts;
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   }
  };
```

This the smart contract

```
    //list a new set of products in the store for sale
    function listNewProduct(
        address _seller,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _rating,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _description,
        string memory _category,
        string memory _imgUrl
    ) public {
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender) == true, "Accounts need to be created");
        require(storeExist == true, "you need to own a store to list products");
        require(msg.sender == _seller , "you need to be a seller");
        Product memory newProduct = Product({
            buyer: address(0),
            seller: msg.sender,
            id: productCounter,
            price: _price,
            rating: _rating,
            name: _name,
            description: _description,
            category: _category,
            imgUrl: _imgUrl
        });

        product[productCounter] = newProduct;
        productCounter++;
        products.push(newProduct);
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear where the error originates. It could be that you are sending something to an address parameter something isn't an address.

Comment: I think you are passing an ENS domain instead of an address.
And ENS domains are not supported on mumbai testnet